# Confidence Interval Table

Tags: equation-solving, fitting

I estimated parameters using a transcendental function in the model. The estimate worked using the following commands:

```
f[A_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ, alfa_?NumericQ, x1_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[{x1*
      Exp[(1 - x1)^2*((tal21*G21^2)/(x1 + (1 - x1)*G21)^2 + (
          G12*tal12)/((1 - x1) + x1*G12)^2)]*P1sat + (1 - x1)*
      Exp[x1^2*((G21*tal21)/(x1 + (1 - x1)*G21)^2 + (
          tal12*G12^2)/((1 - x1) + x1*G12)^2)] *P2sat - Ptotal}, {T, 
    300}][[1, 2]]
Modelx1 = 
 NonlinearModelFit[
  dadosx1, {f[A, B, alfa, x1], 
   0.299999 < alfa < 0.3}, {{A, 100}, {B, 100}, {alfa, 0.3}}, x1]

Modelx1["BestFitParameters"]
```

But I would like to generate a table with mean, standard deviation and confidence interval. Can anyone help me how can i do this? I used the command Modelx1 ["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"] and it didn't work.

Comment: Please include what about it didn't work.  Was there an error message?  Nothing returned?

Comment: When I used the command Print[Modelx1["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]] several error messages appeared and also Missing []

Comment: While there are some really good mind-readers in this forum, I am not one of them.  Could you be more explicit about the error messages?  Those error messages have pretty strong hints as to what the issue might be.  In fact, that's their reason for being.

Comment: As @Jim mentioned, please do not make us guess at your problem. Include the value of `dadosx1` and all the other variables included in your model so we can run your code, and show the exact errors you get.

Comment: Sorry: Print[Modelx1["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]]

FittedModel::constr: The property values {ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable} assume an unconstrained model. The results for these properties may not be valid, particularly if the fitted parameters are near a constraint boundary.

Comment: That was the first error message. Have many.

Comment: That's a good start but that's just a warning message about the standard error of `alfa` because you placed limits on that parameter estimator.  Also, your starting value for `alfa` is outside of the limits you used.  Maybe trying something inside the range of values?

Comment: Instead of estimating alpha, I used a constant value of 0.3 and the problem was not solved. I was able to estimate the parameters but not get the table.

Comment: FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-101.3+0.0452 2.71828^(2.63916 +0.911643 (Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<4>>]))+0.9548 2.71828^(0.831666 +0.00204304 (Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<4>>]))} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {T} = {300.}.

Comment: Part::partw: Part 2 of {0.0452 Exp[(1+Times[<<2>>])^2 (tal21 Power[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>]+G12 tal12 Power[<<2>>])] P1sat+(1-0.0452) Exp[0.0452^2 (G21 tal21 Power[<<2>>]+tal12 Power[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>])] P2sat-Ptotal} does not exist.

Comment: FittedModel::varnum: The estimated variance 1/19 (0.00225391 +1. (385.85 -FindRoot[{<<1>>},{<<2>>}][[1,2]])^2+1. (381.65 -FindRoot[{<<1>>},{<<2>>}][[1,2]])^2+1. (378.15 -FindRoot[{<<1>>},{<<2>>}][[1,2]])^2+<<12>>+1. (356.65 -FindRoot[{<<1>>},{<<2>>}][[1,2]])^2+1. (355.85 -FindRoot[{<<1>>},{<<2>>}][[1,2]])^2+1. (354.95 -FindRoot[{<<1>>},{<<2>>}][[1,2]])^2+1. (354.15 -FindRoot[{<<1>>},{<<2>>}][[1,2]])^2) is not a positive number. Properties requiring division by the variance or standard error will not be computed.